# ¿Cómo borro el carácter introducido por la tecla "Intro" al leer un archivo .txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo

Tengo un documento .txt el cual es un diccionario inglés (cada línea es una palabra). Estoy intentando agregar al principio de cada palabra "*http://www.*" y al final "*.com*".

La tarea de copiar "*http://www.*" al principio de cada palabra lo hace correctamente, pero cuando intento agregar el "*.com*" lo hace en la línea siguiente, para los que no lo hayan entendido adjunto una imagen:

[image: ~]

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
import os

count = 0


file = open("englishdictionary.txt", "r")
newfile = open("newenglishdictionary.txt", "a")
while count != 466544: # Este numero es el total de palabras del diccionario
    word = file.readline(count)
    newword = "http://www." + word + ".com"
    newfile.write(newword)
    count = count + 1
```

¿Cómo puedo conseguir que el ".com" se añada al final de cada palabra, al estilo de "http://www.door.com"? ¿Es un carácter invisible que hace la función de "Intro", y si es así, cómo lo elimino?

Esto es un fragmento del archivo original (*englishdictionary.txt*):

> delays
>   Delamare
>   Delambre
>   delaminate
>   delaminated
>   delaminating
>   delamination
>   Delancey
>   Deland
>   Delaney
>   Delanie
>   Delannoy
>   Delano

Comment: Usa [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) sobre cada línea para eliminar los posibles caracteres de nueva línea (\n) o retornos de carro (\r) del final de cada una. ¿466544 es el número de líneas del fichero? Lo digo porque si es eso lo que haces es ineficiente.

Comment: @FJSevilla ¿Podrías editar mi código implementando str.rstrip()? Lo estoy intentando yo y no me funciona. Gracias

Comment: En principio se lo debes aplicar a `word`. `file.readline(count).rstrip()`. Si muestras un pequeño fragmento del archivo original,  el fragmento que da lugar  lugar a la salida que pones en la imagen  vendría genial, sería más fácil responder adecuadamente. Hay varias cosas que se pueden mejorar en el código, como la concatenación de cadenas que haces. También te falta añadir un salto de línea después de `.com`. Si puedes agregar el trocito de englishdictionary.txt como texto no como una imágen sería de gran ayuda.Para ello usa el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/155347/edit)

Comment: @FJSevilla voy, dame 10 minutos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unas cuantas observaciones primero:

- `readline` retorna una línea nueva cada vez que es llamada. Una línea está delimitada por el carácter fin de línea. Este carácter especial depende del sistema operativo, pudiendo ser un carácter de salto de línea (`\n`) como en los sistemas *NIX, retorno de carro (`\r`) antiguos MacOS, retorno de carro + salto de línea (`\r\n`) en Windows, etc. Es importante tener en cuenta que `readline`/`readlines` **no elimina** este carácter cuando retorna la línea.
- `readlines` recibe como argumento opcional el número de bytes/caracteres a retornar, no el número de línea.
- La concatenación de cadenas es muy ineficiente dado que son inmutables, por lo que cuando se concatenan hay que crear un nuevo objeto y eventualmente el GC eliminará los anteriores. `str.join`, por ejemplo, es mucho más eficiente.
- `write`/`writelines` no añaden saltos de línea nunca, por lo que es necesario que los añadas tú a cada línea de forma explícita.
- No se si lo haces o no, pero no lo muestras en el código. **Siempre tienes que cerrar un archivo** cuando termines de trabajar con el. No dejes esta tarea al recolector de basura, puedes encontrarte con sorpresas no deseadas. Usar el manejador de contexto con `with` suele ser la mejor opción para no olvidarse de ello.
- Si pretendes recorrer línea a línea el fichero un `while` y `readline` es una opción muy ineficiente además de más complicada que usar un simple `for line in file`.

Con todo esto, para eliminar los caracteres de nueva línea lo más simple es usar [`str.rstript()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip). Retorna una nueva cadena eliminando las posibles coincidencias encontradas al final de la cadena  con la subcadena pasada como argumento. Si no se le pasa argumento elimina todos los caracteres de nueva línea o espacios sobrantes.

En principio tu código podría quedar:

```
with open("englishdictionary.txt") as input_file,\
     open("newenglishdictionary.txt", "a") as output_file:

    lines = (''.join(("http://www.", line.rstrip(), ".com\n")) for line in input_file)
    output_file.writelines(lines)
```

si se usa Python 3.6 y en adelante los literales de cadena formateados son más eficientes que `str.join`:

```
with open("englishdictionary.txt") as input_file,\
     open("newenglishdictionary.txt", "a") as output_file:

    lines = (f"http://www.{line.rstrip()}.com\n" for line in input_file)
    output_file.writelines(lines)
```

> **Nota**: `lines` es un generador, esto implica que en ningún momento cargamos en memoria el archivo. Se va leyendo línea a línea del fichero de entrada al mismo tiempo que se va guardando la línea procesada en el fichero de salida.

Para un fichero como:

> hello
>   stack
>   overflow

Obtenemos:

> http://www.hello.com
>   http://www.stack.com
>   http://www.overflow.com

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, has solucionado el problema.